# Spark: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-streaming

I get this error when I run the code below

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._

object PopularTwitterHashtags {


  def setupTwitter() = {
    import scala.io.Source

    for (line <- Source.fromFile("data/twitter.txt").getLines) {
      val fields = line.split(" ")
      if (fields.length == 2) {
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth." + fields(0), fields(1))
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    setupTwitter()

    
    val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[*]", "PopularHashtags", Seconds(1))
    val sc = ssc.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)

    val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.getText())

    val tweetwords = statuses.flatMap(tweetText => tweetText.split(" "))

    val hashtags = tweetwords.filter(word => word.startsWith("#"))


    val hashtagKeyValues = hashtags.map(hashtag => (hashtag, 1))


    val hashtagCounts = hashtagKeyValues.reduceByKeyAndWindow( (x,y) => x + y, (x,y) => x - y, Seconds(300), Seconds(1))

    val sortedResults = hashtagCounts.transform(rdd => rdd.sortBy(x => x._2, false))

    sortedResults.print

    ssc.checkpoint("data")
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

I don't know what library or part of the code uses this `org/apache/spark/Logging`. The only part that have something to do with logging is when I call `sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")`. But I've tried removing that and I still get this error.

I'm using sbt for dependencies. My sbt file is

```
name := "SparkStreaming"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "1.6.3",
)
```

UPDATE:

People told me that the problem was using `spark-streaming-twitter_2.11` with Scala 2.12. But that's not the case, I've changed to Scala 2.11 and I still get the exact same error. Here's the new sbt file

```
name := "SparkStreaming"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.7",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.7",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.7",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.6.3"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `org.apache.spark.Logging` is only available in Spark 1.5.2 or lower, and this class is a dependency of `org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter`.

Since Spark 1.5.2 is not available for Scala 2.12, we should downgrade to Scala 2.11.

So a sbt file that makes this application works is the following

```
name := "SparkStreaming"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.6.3"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scala version is 2.12, but you're referencing the spark-streaming-twitter_**2.11** library which is built on scala 2.11. Scala 2.11 and 2.12 are incompatible, and that's what's giving you this error.

If you want to use Spark 3, you'd have to use a different dependency that supports scala 2.12.

Comment: I've tried with Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.4.7, but I've got the same error.

Comment: Did you `sbt clean`? I'm not familiar with sbt, but if you build the code with maven, sometimes the old jars with the wrong version would pollute your workspace.

Comment: I found in another question that the problem is that `org.apache.spark.Logging` is only available in Spark 1.5.2 or lower. So I changed the Spark version to 1.5.2 an it worked.